# How can I correct my formatting Problem?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I tried to format My Microsoft Word 2007 for a mail merge and I totally I screwed up my formatting.  Now every time I try to cut and paste a link, I get something like this:

{HYPERLINK”https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout?returnurl=%2fquestions%fask”}

Every time I try to insert a date, this is what I get: {DATE\@”M/dyyyy”}

Every time I try to insert a date, this is what I get: {PAGE *MERGEFORMAT}

How can I solve this format dilemma?

Comment: That sounds like a question for http://www.superuser.com

Comment: Have you tried pressing Alt + F9?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the right place to be asking msword questions. SO is about programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a mail merge the raw file it self will only show 'code like' information for the date, hyperlinks, page numbers, field where the persons name and other information is to go, ... etc. When all the info in finally merged, meaning complete with all names of persons etc., the proper information will be displayed on the document.